# in postgres, how to RI array elements?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, constraints

with regular RI

```
create table t2(
  c1     serial    primary key,
  c2     int       references t1(c1) on delete cascade
);
create index t2_c2 on t1(c2);
```

what if `c2` were an `Array` of integers?

1. is there any way to `reference` elements of the array
2. what is the best way to make sure the elements are indexed

```
create table t2(
   c1     serial    primary key,
   c2     int[]     -- ??
}
create index t2_c2 on t2( ?? );
```

(sure this has been asked and answered a thousand times, but for some reason out of my google-enable sphere)

Comment: You can have a FK to an index element. If you need that, create a properly normalized 1:many relationship.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, classically I have been, but here's what I find myself doing now, for example: tags. instead of a entity1 x tags, I'm using a `tag_arr int[]` as a column in `entity1` - much easier programming in every respect _except_ RI.